# Why are the areas non-positive?

Tags: integration, education

I learnt that the integral of a function $f(\cdot)$ is the measure of an area, i.e. $\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is the area of the intersection of $x=a$, $x=b$, and $y=f(x)$.

How come some areas are non-positive.

Example: $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos x\,\mathrm{d}x=0\leq 0$.

Comment: The integral only measure the area is the curve is above the $x$ axis. When you use it to calculate the area take in consideration that the integral of a curve below the x axis will be the negative value of the area. In your example, the area of $\cos x$ from $0$ to $\pi /2$ is exactly the same that the area from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$, but the last one is below the x axis.

Comment: Because the area may be located **under** the X-axis. If the area located above the X-axis is smaller than the area located under the X-axis, then the total area computed by the integral is negative. In your example, however, I believe that the total area is $0$, since half of it is above the X-axis and half of it is below the X-axis.

Comment: @barakmanos The OP is completely correct to say that areas cannot be negative. And quite *clearly*, the area between $\cos x$ and the $x$-Axis is *not* zero between $0$ and $\pi$. It's the *difference* between the parts of the area that lies above that $x$-Axis, and the parts that lie below, that is zero.

Comment: @fgp: That's why I wrote, "**the total area computed by the integral**".

Comment: @barakmanos But the integral doesn't compute an area, that's the whole point. It computes the difference between two areas. Introducing "negative areas" doesn't clarify things IMHO, it only add further confusion. Look at the definition of the *lebesgue* integral - it's very clear there how the negative parts of a functions are dealt with.

Comment: @fgp: Well... You've got a point. Perhaps I should have written "the value computed by the integral".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not true, in general, that $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ is equal to the *area* between $f(x)$ and the $x$-Axis in the interval $[a,b]$. For precisely the reason you stated - areas obviously cannot be negative.

What *is* true is that for *non-negative* functions $f(x)$, the area between $f(x)$ and the $x$-Axis in the interval $[a,b]$ is $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$. Though note that this is more a *definition* of that area then anything else - how would you compute that area *without* resorting to integration? The only thing you can really *prove* is that this notion of area coincides with other definitions of area for *simple* shapes like rectangles.

For general functions $fx$, $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ is the *difference* between the area above the $x$-Axis and below $f(x)$, and the area below the $x$-Axis and above $f(x)$. We chose to define the integral that way because it then has a lot of convenient properties. For example, we then get $$
  \int_a^b - f(x) = -\int_a^b f(x) \text{.}
$$

For similar reasons, we also define $$
  \int_a^b f = - \int_b^a f \text{.}
$$

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to compute the area between the curve and the $x$ axis (y = 0) is *split* the integral. At $\pi/2$, the graph of $\cos x$ intersects the $x$ axis (the line $y = 0$). For values $0 \lt x \lt \pi/2$, $\cos x$ is above the $x$ axis.  For values $\pi/2 \lt x \lt \pi$, $\cos x$ is below the line $y = 0$.

To compute the area bound by the line $y = 0$ and $\cos x$, we split the integral into two integrals, subtracting the lower curve from the upper curve.

$$\begin{align} \int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos x - 0)\,dx + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi (0 - \cos x)\,dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos x \,dx - \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos x \,dx \\ \\ &= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos x\,dx\end{align}$$